# how to call arduino codes using topics

Tags: arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the codes are dc motor controller, PID controller, ultrasonic sensor

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277474/how-to-call-arduino-codes-using-topics/) by [pamis5](https://answers.ros.org/users/32889/pamis5/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-12-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-06**:
Welcome! What do you mean by "call arduino codes using topics"? What are you trying to accomplish? Also, please see http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to interact with Arduino from ROS you have to do it by serial communication. I think the simplest way is python scripting.
I did it a few years ago. I had implement a protocol with SYNC, OP_ID, PARAMETERS and CHECKSUM between the PC (ROS) and Arduino

This was my Python script imports:

```
  ...
    import rospy
    import os
    import comm
    from datetime import datetime
    ....
```

where comm is the python file wich manages communication with arduino board

Here I am reading a message from arduino in my ros node file (this is the arduino objetc: ArdIfc)

```
...
  newMsg = ArdIfc.recv()
            if newMsg != None:
                if newMsg.mod == comm.MOD_SENSORS: 
                    if newMsg.op == comm.OP_GETCURRENTDIST:
                        torsoPos = newMsg.param[0]
...
```

Here I am sending a message to the Arduino from my ros node file

```
...
 rospy.loginfo("Torso-> Stop message.")
                msgMotor = comm.Msg(comm.ARDUINO_ID, comm.MOD_MOTORS, comm.OP_STOP_MOTOR, [], 0)
                ArdIfc.send(msgMotor)
                msgMotor_ack_received = False 
...
```

If you want the code I can send it to you.

best,
Fedeico

---

Originally posted by [fandrade](https://answers.ros.org/users/26822/fandrade/) with karma: 81 on 2017-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-06**:
@fandrade instead of privately sharing code, can you please update your answer with it instead? That way the entire community can benefit from it instead of just one person.

**Comment by [fandrade](https://answers.ros.org/users/26822/fandrade/) on 2017-12-06**:
@jayess if this is what @pamis5 need, I completeley agree to share the files here. Since I am not sure about the real question, I am waiting for his answer.

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-01-15**:
Sir may i learn how to connect a arduino based Robotic arm with MoveIt

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-15**:
@lagankapoor: comments aren't an appropriate place to ask questions. You should create your own question instead of asking in a comment.

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-01-17**:
thanks sir
check i ask new question today please if you know about that help me